# Android: Handle transformClassesWithDexForRelease error from gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I am using one 3rd party library by adding it in gradle dependencies.  But unfortunately I am having some dex errors when creating the final build.(below image)

[image]

In gradlew app:dependancies command, I got the below hierarchy for the library.

[image]

First I thought, the issue might be for recycleView.So I tried by excluding the recycleView module from this library like:

```
compile ('com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.4.7'){
        exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    }
```

But nothing happened.

Is anyone knows, how to solve this kind of issue. Or what to exclude from this library to solve this dex issue ?

*EDIT*

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.fs.analytics')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.application.gaf')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.catalog')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.category')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.consumeraccount')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.core')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.location')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.mediasharing')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.fs.notification')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.product.catalog')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.schedule')
compile project(':com.beeonics.android.services')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.store')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.fs.barcode')
compile project(':FoundationServices:com.beeonics.android.fs.map')
compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
compile project(':beeonics-mfc-android-contacts')
compile 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.4.7'

//compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

//acra
compile ('ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile ('com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

// Retrofit stuffs
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
enforceUniquePackageName = false
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-
    types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... 
    which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
}
```

Comment: Please mention what I did wrong here before giving any negative vote so I can make it perfect.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`. I am not sure that the problem is the recyclerview. In any case if you want to exclude the recyclerview the right name of the module is `exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for the reply. I have attached the build.gradle file. As per my understanding, the issue is coming after adding `compile 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.4.7'` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolve the issue after a long experiment.

The issue `transformClassesWithDexForRelease'` was coming at the time of release build. After a small research I found that this issue is related multiple reasons like jar/library version mismatch, jar/library duplicate, conflict etc.

After checking the dependency hierarchy (gradlew app:dependencies)  I found that the 3rd party library which I used is using some other libraries with higher versions. So I just took the library code and implement it in my application with putting proper dependency library version in gradle.

It resolved somehow but not the whole problem. The same issue `transformClassesWithDexForRelease'`. Then I again check the hierarchy and found that only `support-annotations` and `support-v4` which are mostly coming in almost libraries are the main cause here also.

Then finally I excluded these two libraries from the Recycle-View and able to build the app.

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```